# remove woocommerce storefront homepage title php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, storefront

I am using storefront theme by woocommerce. I need to remove homepage title (h1) with php, i know css solution, but i don't want to use it, because i want to add h1 to other place in that page and it's bad for seo to have 2 h1's in one page! I also know about plugins that remove page title, but they are working as css display:none; property!

I tried all the snippets that i could find in web, but no luck!

Here is my site domain BrightBells.com

Here is PHP code snippets that i tried one by one by adding to my functions.php file, but none of its help!

Snippet 1

```
function wc_hide_page_title() {
if( is_front_page() ) 
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'wc_hide_page_title' );
```

Snippet 2

```
function sf_change_homepage_title( $args ) {
remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'sf_change_homepage_title' );
```

Snippet 3

```
function sf_change_homepage_title( $args ) {
remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10 );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'sf_change_homepage_title' );
```

Snippet 4

```
function sf_change_homepage_title( $args ) {
remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'sf_change_homepage_title' );
```

Snippet 5

```
function sf_change_homepage_title( $args ) {
if(is_front_page()) {
    remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10 );
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'sf_change_homepage_title' );
```

Snippet 6

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header' );
}
```

Snippet 7

```
if ( is_page('page id') )
{
  add_filter( 'the_title', '__return_false' );
}
```

None of this snippets help, please help!

Here is page settings screenshots!
[setting page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfDgo.png)

[page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMQXZ.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use CSS for home page only. In the body, you have a unique class for home so you can use it. Because only one title is there in your page. so body.home h1.entry-title{ display:none; } works and not will affect in any inner pages.

Comment: @Gajjar Chintan Hello, thanks for answer, i dont mean its affects to inner pages, i mean i have another h1 on homepage, and with css, its just hide the title for user, but google still saw that there is 2 h1's at one page

Comment: @Und3rTow Thank you very much i tried it, but still not help

Comment: what is your settings in **Settings > Reading > Front page displays**, are you using a page template?

Comment: @Reigel thanks for answer, i set it to static front page, and selected my homepage static page from dropdown. i will edit post and will take scrrenshots of settings now!

Comment: @VoskanyanT, You are right. In your site, there are more than one h1. But "h1.entry-title"  h1 with entry-title is unique in your page so you can use it. That's why I told you to use this css : body.home h1.entry-title{ display:none; }

Comment: @GajjarChintan, thanks for answering, but i dont mean both h1's will be hide with css, i mean if i will hide one h1 with css, it will be hidden for humans, but search engines will still determinate it like having 2 h1's on one page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are using a child theme or plugin in doing this.
Because it will just be removed when your theme updates.

In storefront version 2.2.5, it can be done with this code:

```
remove_action( 'storefront_homepage', 'storefront_homepage_header', 10 );
```

**Update:**
if on a child theme please do something like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_homepage_header' ) ) {
    function storefront_homepage_header() { }
}
```

Child themes are run first before the parent theme. By doing so, we will define this `storefront_homepage_header` function first. In that case, the parent theme will not create it. Applicable only on themes that uses `function_exists`, luckily, storefront does.

`remove_action` will not work because the action has not been added yet.

Comment: thanks for answer i added it to my child theme functions.php, but no luck

Comment: Thank you very much Reigel, i was looking for solution for few days now! Thanks again, mark as answered!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ---

```
if ( is_front_page() || is_home() )
{
  add_filter( 'the_title', '__return_false' );
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what are you doing with this solution?

Comment: it's returning blank title if it is home page

Comment: Please edit your answer

Comment: reason for that ?

Comment: If you need explain what are you doing in your answer, please don't comment, edit your own anser. This is a good guide to anser in S.O. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This will help you also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: I think the code and function names were self explanatory. 
I am sorry that you were unable to understand that and needed an explanation in first place.
If you would have gone though the question, it might have helped you.