# Wordpress Hide Title on Certain Pages Using is_page()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, scope, storefront

I am trying to remove the h1 title on my about page in my functions.php file.

Here is my code:

```
function remove_about_page_title()
{
    if (is_page('about')) {
        remove_action('storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'remove_about_page_title');
```

If I do a var dump on `is_page('about')` then I get `false` even though it is the about page.

If I change my `add_action()` function to run the `remove_about_page_title()` function from init to `storefront_page` then `is_page()` prints true but the remove_action function no longer works.

Is this due to being out of the scope chain?

Is there a way to remove the page header inside the `functions.php` file without CSS and #ids?

Comment: You have to use `is_page('pageId')` instead of `is_page('about')`

Comment: also use `wp` instead `init` and `is_page` works for `page ID, page Slug` make sure `about` is the slug of about page. i think it is the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051486/remove-woocommerce-storefront-homepage-title-php

Comment: @Darshan, superb solution, it works. Noman, this is the best solution because it is not tied to page_id which could (although unlikely) change. Thank you!

Comment: Page ID, title, slug, or array of such

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst, Glad to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for upvote. Feel free to accept my answer if the solution addressed your concern. @JethroHazelhurst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `is_page('pageId')` instead of `is_page('about')`;

Answer (score 1):

I would make an array in your functions.php file that holds the page names that you want to hide the title on.

functions.php

```
$noTitle = array("page1", "page2");
```

header.php

```
if(in_array($title, $noTitle)){
    //no title
}
else{
    //title
}
```

At least I think you can do it this way. You may want to check when functions.php gets loaded. If it is not loaded by now, you may have to make another php file and load it manually at the top of the header.php file.